# update charjs dataset using react library

Tags: reactjs, chart.js

I created pretty easy curves with the library chartjs.
I have created a simple input field or I can select a number. I would like to be able to update this data line: [5, 7, 4, 2, 1, 8, 7, 2, 5].
For example, if we put the number 3, it replaces 5 by 3. I stuck on this problem.
Any help will be very helpful, thank you very much!

I attach my code below.

```
this.state = {
  value: '',
  data: {
    labels: ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"], // nb jours
    datasets: [
      {
        type: 'line',
        label: "Hour of sleep",
        backgroundColor: 'transparent',
        borderColor: 'green',
        pointRadius: 3,
        data: [6, 8, 7, 8, 7, 7, 7, 8, 9, 6] // pour l instant on part du principe que dormir 10 heure c est le meilleur.
      },
      {
        type: 'line',
        backgroundColor: 'transparent',
        borderColor: 'orange',
        label: "Fruits and legume",
        pointRadius: 3,
        data: [5, 7, 4, 2, 1, 8, 7, 2, 5] // faire un select qui selon le jour remplis le tableaux data.
      },
    ]
  }
}

render() {
return(
  <div style={{ position: "relative", width: "80%", height: "50%"}}>
  <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
  <input type="number" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange} /><input type="submit" value="ok" />
  </form>
    <Line
      options={{
        responsive: true
      }}
      data = {this.state.data}
    />
  </div>
)
```

}

```
handleChange = (e) => {
let value = e.target.value;
this.setState({
  value: value
});
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to add redraw={true} to Line component?

```
<Line
  options={{
    responsive: true
  }}
  data = {this.state.data}
  redraw={true}
/>
```

If it doesn't work, can you please provide also `handleChange` and `handleSubmit` functions

Comment: Ok i will edit my post, thansk how i can access to my data tab ? with this.state.data.data[0] i think ?

Comment: You want the first value to change according to the input you provided, right? if yes, this is a small demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-chartjs-2-example-3erip?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark